# Can't append a Child to a newly created one (HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, events, append

```
    <style>
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

        div h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }

    section {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    input[type=text] {
        padding: 3px;
        width:150px;
        height:10px;
    }

</style>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Tuesday TODO List</h1>
    <input type="text" id="sectionText" class="sectionText" placeholder="Title" />
    <button id="btn" class="btn">New Section</button>
</div></body>
```

My Script

```
var a = document.getElementById('btn');
a.addEventListener('click', function () {
var b = document.createElement('section');
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(b);
}, false);
```

So far the script works, but i want to append a child and set it's id to  ***var b*** and when i try it, it doesn't works.

```
var d = document.createElement('INPUT');
d.setAttribute('type', 'text').setId('id name');
b.appendChild(d);
```

And this 3 lines when i put them ***inside of the event listener*** it doesn't works, i just separated them outside for convenience

Comment: `d.setAttribute('type', 'text')` returns `undefined`. You cannot do chaining in DOM Api like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should have to be like this,

```
var d = document.createElement('INPUT');
d.setAttribute('type', 'text')
d.setAttribute('id', 'id name');
```

- Since `setAttribute` doesn't return anything rather than `undefined`.
  You can't chain it.
- There is no function like `setId` available by default in the node's
  proto. You have to use `setAttribute` for setting an id.

Comment: ok, thank you but it still doesn't appends to var b, can you explain to me how to append it

Comment: @ВсеЕдно Did you use this line in your code? `b.appendChild(d);` I skipped it here since that is not required for answering.